# How to select an unaliased numeric literal from a sub-select

Tags: sql, alias, subquery

I'm wondering if there is a general SQL syntax allowing for selecting unaliased numeric literals from sub-selects:

```
-- Seems to work in MySQL / Oracle
select table_alias."1"
from (
   select 1 from dual
) table_alias
```

I know I could alias the fields in the subselect:

```
-- Works everywhere
select table_alias.column_alias
from (
   select 1 column_alias from dual
) table_alias
```

But what if I don't have control over the subselect? Also, some RDBMS allow to provide both table AND column aliases when aliasing tables:

```
-- Seems to work in Postgres / SQL Server
select table_alias.column_alias
from (
  select 1 from dual
) table_alias (column_alias)
```

But some RDBMS (e.g. MySQL) can't do that. Is there another way?

- Note: This isn't about any specific RDBMS, but just SQL in general
- Note: I'd like to omit the asterisk, i.e. no `select *`...

A related question is this one here:

[Is there a generic workaround to express a derived column list in Oracle (and MySQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127707/is-there-a-generic-workaround-to-express-a-derived-column-list-in-oracle-and-my)

Comment: run it as select * from ()... ?

Comment: @Randy, I forgot to mention that I want to omit the asterisk

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server (or something else)?  In SQL Server, you have to give your columns an alias when using derived tables.

Comment: @Jerad: Like the third example? That's also valid in Postgres, for instance...

Comment: If its a hard wired literal, why even have it in the sub query in the first place?

Comment: @Limey: Consider this to be a rather academic question about syntax in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the ANSI-92 standard it is implementation dependent. From section 7.9, 9.c:

> Otherwise, the <column name> of the i-th column of the  is implementation-dependent and different from the
>   <column name> of any column, other than itself, of a table referenced
>   by any <table reference> contained in the SQL-statement.

In other words, it's all going to depend on the RDBMS that you're using at the time.

BTW, you can check out [the ANSI-92 standards](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) if you're looking for some fun reading.

Comment: Found it, thanks for the pointer. I know this document, but I clearly don't know how to read it when it comes to such detail ... :-) Alright, so I have no luck. There isn't even a way to access columns by that `i` index? I have never seen such an access-by-index syntax, so I don't believe there is...

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can do

```
select aa."2" from ( select 2 from dual ) aa
```

Comment: I had the impression that this didn't work, for instance with 10g...?

Comment: I actually tried it and made sure. Not really sure what you would use it for , but it does work.

Comment: You're right, it does work in Oracle. I'm sorry, the question was maybe a bit weird. This is for syntax abstraction in a database framework. I need to know the general rule for these sorts of use cases. Or the per-RDBMS rules